# How can I know which user has cron jobs configured on a machine with 200+ users?

Tags: centos, cron

I need to build a new machine and copy properties and some `cron jobs` from another machine which has about 200+ users and I don't know which users have `cron jobs` configured.
Is there a way to extract the list of users which has `cron jobs` configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about looking in the crontabs spool directory?  On my machine (CentOS 6), that's `/var/spool/cron`:

```
[me@lory ~]$ sudo ls -al /var/spool/cron/
total 56
drwx------.  2 root     root  4096 Nov 23  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root     root  4096 Aug 16  2012 ..
-rw-------.  1 root     root   252 Oct  2  2008 carol
-rw-------.  1 root     root   504 Sep 22  2006 david
-rw-------.  1 root     root   515 Sep 22  2006 gsy
-rw-------.  1 root     users  191 Mar 19  2005 hfeinst
-rw-------.  1 ja       ja     147 Jun 26  2013 ja
-rw-------.  1 jkript   root   690 Jan  2  2012 jkript
-rw-------.  1 root     root    90 Feb  1  2007 lu
[...]
```

Comment: Don't overlook the cron jobs set by your fellow administrators which can be in anywhere in `/etc/crontab` , `/etc/cron.d/` , `/etc/cron.[hourly|daily|weekly|monthly]` in addition to `/var/spool/cron/root`.

Comment: An excellent point, and thank you for making it, even though the original question specifies users' jobs.

Comment: non-privileged users vs admin users.